# Sort UITableview in objective c with dates descending NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Thank you for looking into my question here.  I am trying to get uitableview sectioned by dates in descending order. I get the data from the sqllite order by datefield desc.   But whatever I do the dates are displayed in ascending order. I have the following set of data that comes out of the db and in this order:

```
ID BookName DateRead
1  ABC      19-10-2011
2  ABZ      27-06-2011
3  ABD      28-05-2011
```

I would like the data to appear like the following

```
19-10-2011  
ABC 
27-06-2011  
ABZ
28-05-2011  
ABD
```

but no matter what I am trying I am getting the data returned as below:
    19-10-2011
    ABC
    28-05-2011
    ABZ
    27-06-2011
    ABD

Here is the complete list of code that I am using:
.h file

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    @interface BookHistoryViewController : UITableViewController {
        NSArray *books;
        NSMutableDictionary *sections; 
    }
    @property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *books;
    @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *sections;

@end
```

Here is my .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    TestAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


   [Book getInitialDataToDisplay:[appDelegate getDBPath]];



    self.books = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.bookArray];


    self.sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];



    BOOL found;

    // Loop through the books and create our keys

    for (NSDictionary *book in books)
    {    


        NSString *c = [book valueForKey:@"DateRead"];

        found = NO;

        for (NSString *str in [self.sections allKeys])
        {
            if ([str isEqualToString:c])
            {
                found = YES;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {     
            [self.sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
        }
    }

    // Loop again and sort the books into their respective keys
    for (NSDictionary *book in self.books)
    {
        [[self.sections valueForKey:[book valueForKey:@"DateRead"]] addObject:book];
    }    

    // Sort each section array
    for (NSString *key in [self.sections allKeys])
    {
        [[self.sections objectForKey:key] sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"DateRead" ascending:NO]]];
    }    

    [super viewDidLoad];

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    return [[self.sections allKeys] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    return [[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] objectAtIndex:section];


}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSDictionary *book = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [book valueForKey:@"title"];    


    return cell;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the book in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you first sort by section key which is the dateRead as a string, but you sort in ascending order.  You probably want to sort using a descriptor like you do in `viewDidLoad`.  In fact, why not just keep it in the correctly sorted order so that you don't have to sort each time you need a cell?  The way you are doing it will cause the interface to grind to a halt pretty quickly.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy for your reply.I have taken the sorting out from the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: but still it is showing the dates in ascending order.

Comment: You still need the sort there because NSDictionary does not order its keys, but you need to sort with a descriptor like you do in viewDidLoad